# Use Eclipse RCP GUI in other applications

Tags: java, user-interface, migration, eclipse-rcp

We are redesigning a few of our applications to a new custom framework. Now we want a stage to reuse the Eclipse RCP application GUI and redesign the backend (without using Eclipse RCP framework). So we can easily switch the GUI part to JavaFX. Is it possible to only use the GUI parts of the Eclipse RCP framework without using the Eclipse RCP framework?

We don't want all the Eclipse RCP configuration crap in our new projects and we only need the full GUI layer.

Comment: A correctly designed RCP doesn't have any 'configuration crap' whatever that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in an Eclipse RCP is an Eclipse/OSGi plug-in and depends on the OSGi plug-in system to work.

If you depend on existing 3.x compatibility mode plug-ins then you are stuck using the 3.x style RCP.

If you don't depend on 3.x mode plug-ins you may be able to use the e4 style RCP which can set up to look any way you like and can be written using JavaFX instead of SWT using the e(fx)clipse code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use the Eclipse RCP framework without using the Eclipse RCP framework. You might want to look at [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) which allows you to sue the Eclipse RCP framework with a Java FX layer